# I keep getting The below errors on my log file whenever i try to Push my django app to Heroku, Kindly assist on how i should go about in solving it,

Tags: django, heroku

Here is my log file

```
 $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
       utility.execute()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
       django.setup()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
       app_config.ready()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
       self.module.autodiscover()
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
       autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
       import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
       __import__(name)
     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/registration/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
       from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
   ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: `ImportError: cannot import name RequestSite` seems clear enough...

Comment: have you applied `makemigration` and `migrate` commands after changing in models?

Comment: @MarcB, That import is for my registration model and it works perfect in my development server, it just throws that error when i try to push it to heroku, How do you suggest i go about it?

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool Yes i did, and i have applied the migrations again, it still throws that error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequestSite was moved from django.contrib.sites.models to django.contrib.sites.requests in Django 1.7, and the alias in models was removed in Django 1.9. You should ensure you are running a version of django-registration that is compatible with the version of Django you are using.